# secure-delete, "Warning: Couldn't find a free filename for X"

Tags: 16.04, secure-erase

I want to use `secure-delete` to securely delete folders/files and I did the following test:

```
mkdir foldertest
echo "something" > foldertest/filetest.txt
srm -rv foldertest/
```

here the results:

```
Using /dev/urandom for random input.
Wipe mode is secure (38 special passes)
Wiping foldertest/ DIRECTORY (going recursive now)
Wiping filetest.txt ************************************** Removed file filetest.txt ... Done
Warning: Couldn't find a free filename for foldertest/!
Removed directory foldertest/ ... Done
```

The folder `foldertest` (and its content) was deleted successfully, but I don't get the warning:

```
Warning: Couldn't find a free filename for foldertest/!
```

Did the secure cancellation procedure occur without any problems?

Specs:

- ubuntu 4.4.0-75-generic
- secure-delete 3.1-6ubuntu1

Thanks

Comment: Here is the source: http://secure-delete.sourcearchive.com/documentation/3.1/sdel-lib_8c-source.html Nothing else found on this notice :P

Comment: yeah.. I've already found your link, but nothing seems to be very clear for me. Another one is [link](http://www.wikihow.com/Permanently-Delete-Files#Linux_-_Using_Secure-Delete_sub) (5th step), but nothing technically useful

Answer (score 0):

I think it's the slash at the end of your srm line:

```bash
srm -rv foldertest/
```

(I guess it appeared cos you used <kbd>Tab</kbd> to autocomplete the filename in your shell.)

srm doesn't seem to like a slash being at the end of a directory name. I've emailed the guy to find out if the warning can be ignored, or if it means the filename has not been overwritten with random data. I'll update if he replies.

---

**Edit, summary:** He says that if you see that warning then the data inside the dir has been securely erased, but the filename of the directory has not, and could be forensically recovered. Leaving off the slash stops the error for me, so I'll be doing that, though that's just me - he doesn't confirm my idea (see his reply below).

(Autocomplete is of course so useful that a bash function using `sed` to strip slashes from the end of arguments might be one way to go if losing the slash works for you.)

Full reply from developer (Van Hauser, his email address is in srm manpage):

> Hi,
>
> dunno if the "/" is the problem. I havent looked at the code for ... 10
>   years now? ;)
>   but all data is wiped. the only thing that is not happening is that
>   test_dir is not renamed, so that directory name could still be
>   recoverable by forensics.
>
> Regards,
>   vh

("test_dir" is just the equivalent of your "foldertest" in the code sample I sent him)